# Deleting specific rows having null values in multiple specified columns in a dataframe using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataset that contains 23 columns and 71k rows and I want to remove the rows which have null values in multiple given columns.

Let's say we have columns a,b,c,d,e,f,g and i want to remove the rows as per the condition:

Values in columns a,b,c,d are null so there will be use of either & or 'and' for multiple column condition.

Indexing wont help much due to the large dataset so I need some kindof loop to do this task and filter out the data for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with `subset` and `how` arguments:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [np.nan, 1, 2, 3],
                   'b': [np.nan, np.nan, 2, 3],
                   'c': [np.nan, 5, 6, 7],
                   'd': [np.nan, 8, 9, 10],
                   'e': [11, 11, 12, 13],
                   'f': [14, 14, 15, 16]})

df2 = df.dropna(subset=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], how='any')
#    a  b  c   d   e   f
# 2  2  2  6   9  12  15
# 3  3  3  7  10  13  16

df3 = df.dropna(subset=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], how='all')
#    a   b  c   d   e   f
# 1  1 NaN  5   8  11  14
# 2  2   2  6   9  12  15
# 3  3   3  7  10  13  16
```